# How to use Datediff of time in vb.net? From Starting time to Ending time

Tags: vb.net, time, datediff

I need to know the value of time. I mean the interval of time; from **starting time** to **ending time**. Anyone can help? :(

[image]

This is my list and I want to get the interval value of time.

When I select the item/record in the Datagridview2 it will displayed here

Can somebody share an idea/or code? Thanks

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can simply subtract one `Date` from another `Date` and get a `TimeSpan`. You could probably even have found that out for yourself with a web search. For instance, I just searched for *"vb.net find time difference"* and the first result provided a code example. Questions that can be answered that easily don't need to be asked here.

Comment: Sorry the second image is incorrect. It's LABEL by the way, "CLASS HOURS" and just assume that the interval value will displayed here. EX:  "CLASS HOURS: 5"

Comment: E.g., `dim diffInMinutes = (Date2 - Date1).TotalMinutes`. You didn't specify what kind of date/time objects you're working with (DateTime, TimeSpan, other), whether the data is loaded from a database, or if it's User input instead. Also, what the result should look like and used for -- Add all the details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this, you need the `TimeSpan` data type.

In my example, a variable is written with the current time at the beginning of the runtime.
A timer regularly calculates the new time span between time 1 and the current time, and outputs this time span in a text box.

Also, I use `CultureInfo` (I always do, don't be surprised) and I use PadLeft to have leading zeros. Looks nicer.

```
Public Class FormMain
    Private ReadOnly Starttime As Date = Date.Now
    Private ReadOnly Deu As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE")
    Private Sub FormMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim TS As TimeSpan = Date.Now - Starttime
        TextBox1.Text = TS.Minutes.ToString(Deu).PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":" & TS.Seconds.ToString(Deu).PadLeft(2, "0"c)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Stop()
    End Sub
End Class
```